# Spring Kafka: @KafkaListener - Message<T> , Generic type "T" not getting resolved in abstract impl

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

Trying to create abstract class AbstractTestKafka for @KafkaListener with generic type in `Message<T>`.

In concrete class that extends AbstractTestKafka, if we provide type T, MessagingMessageConverter not able to resolve the type T.

Getting -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.demo.Cat (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.demo.Cat is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.spring.kafka.poc.test.TestKafkaImpl.processNew(TestKafkaImpl.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
```

Code:

```java
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
   ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V> factory =
       new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
   initialiseFactory(factory);
   return factory;
 }
 
 private void initialiseFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V> factory) {
   factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
   factory.setAutoStartup(false);
   factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
   factory.setBatchListener(true);
   factory.setConcurrency(1);
 
 //Converter
  factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter()));
 
 }
 
  public ConsumerFactory<K, V> consumerFactory() {
     consumerCofigMap = getConsumerConfigs();
     return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerCofigMap);
   }
```

AbstractTestKafka

```java
public abstract class AbstractTestKafka<T> {
 
     @KafkaListener(id = "newConsumer",topics = "topic1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",autoStartup = "true")
    public void listen(List<Message<T>> messages, Acknowledgment ack){
        Flux.fromIterable(messages)
                .log()
                .flatMap(
                        message -> {
                            return processNew(message);
                        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .blockLast(Duration.ofMillis(6000));
        ;
        ack.acknowledge();
    }


    public abstract Mono<Object> processNew(Message<T> msg) ;

}
```

Concrete class

```java
public class TestKafkaImpl extends AbstractTestKafka<Cat> {
    @Override
    public Mono<Object> processNew(Message<Cat> msg) {
        Cat cat=msg.getPayload();
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

[image: Debugging screen shot]

[image: Debugging screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work; the framework can't infer the generic type T.

You would need to use a Kafka deserializer to create the `Cat` object instead of relying on the framework's inferred type.

**EDIT**

Since there is no type information, the converter is converting to a `Map`.

There are several solutions, including:

- use a `JsonDeserializer` with a type function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods
- use a custom message converter that overrides the inferred type:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75030774Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75030774Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so75030774").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so75030774", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    MessagingMessageConverter converter() {
        return new JsonMessageConverter() {

            @Override
            protected Object extractAndConvertValue(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Type type) {
                return super.extractAndConvertValue(record, Foo.class);
            }

        };
    }

}

abstract class AbsListener<T> {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so75030774", topics = "so75030774")
    void listen(Message<T> in) {
        process(in);
    }

    public abstract void process(Message<T> msg);
}

@Component
class ConcreteListener extends AbsListener<Foo> {

    @Override
    public void process(Message<Foo> msg) {
        System.out.println(msg.getPayload().getClass());
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
We are you using "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer".

is there any work-around if we want to use framework converter, keeping this abtract implementation of listener.

Comment: See the edit to my answer for a couple of solutions.